# Cambiar picturebox al hacer click en celda dgv C#

Tags: c#

Buena tarde me podrian ayudar sobre como hacer el codigo para cambiar la imagen de un picture box en base a un click en un dgv donde se seleccione la celda, este es el codigo que tengo al seleccionar la celda

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow fila = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[5].Value);
            txtid.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            txtacreditacion.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[5].Value);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[7].Value);

            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile ("F1_2.Properties.Resources._" + Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value));

// Mediante las propiedad image si lo cambio manual se define asi F1_2.Properties.Resources._1048


        }
```

ya tengo las imagenes en recursos

Comment: En la celda del grid tienes alguna ruta a la imagen que se selecciona en la fila? o tienes algun id o codigo del registro en la db para ir al recuperar la imagen mediante una consulta a la db

Comment: En la columna [0] de la bd es el id que se asocia con el nombre de la foto

Comment: entonces la foto no se visualiza en el grid en una celda? en la tabla de la db persistes el nombre  unicamente, la ruta completa a la imagen, o es un byte[] ?

Comment: es un el nombre de la imagen,  te actualize como lo estoy intentando

Comment: donde esta tu imagen?? en una base de datos, en un directorio??

Comment: pero la imagen esta en un archivo de recurso, no era que estaba en la db ?

Answer (score 0):

Si la imagen esta como resourse entonces debes usar la clase `ResourceManager`

[ResourceManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8)

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("F1_2.Properties.Resources", typeof(this).Assembly);

var imagen = rm.GetObject(string,Format("_{0}", fila.Cells[0].Value));
pictureBox2.Image = (Image)imagen;
```